# Faster function than an ifelse() in r

Tags: r, if-statement

I have 3 columns **Flag, Score, Stage**.

Flag will have values 1 or 0, Score will be any values above 0. We need to calculate stage values.

so our data (stagedata) will look like this:

```
              Flag Score Stage
               1    35
               1    0
               0    12
               ....
```

IF Flag == 1 and score >= 30, the we calculate stage as 2,

and if Flag ==0 or Flag == 1 and score < 30, stage = 1.

Any other case stage will be calculated as 0 (ie, due to some error in input or if score or flag is missing).

```
        stagedata$Stage <- ifelse(stagedata$Flag==1,ifelse((stagedata$Score>=30),2,1),ifelse(stagedata$Flag==0,1,0))
        stagedata$Stage[is.na(stagedata$Stage)] <-0
```

**IS there a more efficient way to do this using any other function like apply? The data that we are dealing with are of the order of ten thounsands**

Comment: Are there any other options than 1 or 0 for a Flag? e.g., in what case `stagedata$Stage` can be `NA`? I have a feeling you could solve it by just `stagedata$Stage <- 1 ; stagedata[stagedata$Flag == 1 & stagedata$Score >= 30, "Stage"] <- 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert the logical vector to integer with some arithmetic operation

```
v1 <- with(stagedata, 2 *(Flag == 1 & score >= 30) + (Flag %in% 0:1 & score <30))
v1
#[1] 2 1 1 2 1 0
```

If there are NA values, then replace it with 0

```
v1[is.na(v1)] <- 0
```

#### data

```
stagedata <- data.frame(Flag = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2), score = c(35, 0, 12, 31, 27, 31))
```

Comment: Hi @akrun. looks fantastic. Any idea how faster this computes when compared to ifelse?

Comment: Your solution does not provide the same result as OP's - change to `with(stagedata, 2 *(Flag == 1 & Score >= 30) + (Flag == 0 | Score < 30))` and it does - microbenchmarking shows it's 6x faster than OP's and 1.4x faster than your original

Comment: @CPak Even if flag =1, unless score breaches that 30 value, it doesn't move to stage 2

Comment: @CPak How do you get the microbenchmarking score..?

Comment: @akrun - `Flag` can only be in `c(0,1)` - if `(Flag==0) == FALSE` then `Flag` must be 1, in which case only `Score < val` must be checked

Answer (score 2):

The original answer and the fixed answer are different by 1.07x - not 1.4x - not a meaningful difference

```
N <- 10000
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Flag = sample(0:1, N, replace=T), Score = sample(c(12, 35), N, replace=T))
  # Flag Score
# 1    0    12
# 2    0    35
# 3    1    35
# 4    1    12
# 5    0    12
# 6    1    12

ifelse_approach <- function() {
  df$Stage <- ifelse(df$Flag==1,ifelse((df$Score>=30),2,1),ifelse(df$Flag==0,1,0))
}

lgl_approach <- function() {
  df$Stage <- with(df, 2 *(Flag == 1 & Score >= 30) + (Flag %in% 0:1 & Score <30))
}

lgl_fix_approach <- function() {
  df$Stage <- with(df, 2 *(Flag == 1 & Score >= 30) + (Flag == 0 | Score < 30))
}

identical(ifelse_approach(), lgl_approach())
# FALSE
identical(ifelse_approach(), lgl_fix_approach())
# TRUE

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(ifelse_approach(), lgl_approach(), lgl_fix_approach(), unit="relative", times=10L)

# Unit: relative
               # expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
  # ifelse_approach() 5.949921 6.048253 5.714637 6.737770 7.186373 3.0478402    10
     # lgl_approach() 1.120431 1.111262 1.059140 1.274285 1.376115 0.5364108    10
 # lgl_fix_approach() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.0000000    10
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. There is a small issue with the logic you used . Precisely here: (Flag == 0 | Score < 30).

Comment: If Flag is absent ( can happen ) and score is present, it assigns a stage 1.

Comment: Could you take a look at the result of `identical(..., ...)`? I'm not sure what result you're expecting but the results are identical with your ifelse approach - take a look at the first few rows of results using `ifelse_approach()`, `lgl_approach()`, and `lgl_fix_approach()`